# Rewriting $n(2^{2^{n-1}}-1)-2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n-1}+1}$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Could you help me to write in a better way the following expression? (by better I mean for example simplifying if I can)
$$
n(2^{2^{n-1}}-2)-2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n-1}+1}
$$

Comment: This is your 197th question. You should know by now that you have to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n(2^{2^{n-1}}-2)-2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n-1}+1} = 
 2^{2^{n-1}}(n+2-2^{2^{n-1}})-2n$$